# Change and keep the value in a 2D array in a loop

Tags: java, loops

So here is the code I have going so far:

```
static int[][] change() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader ein = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int i = 4;
    int MatrixNew[][] = new int[i][i];

    for (int i = 0; i < MatrixNew.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MatrixNew[i].length; j++) {
            if (MatrixNew[i][j] == 0) { //edit: added content from above into if
                System.out.println("Enter numbers:"); // numbers entered like so: zse 
                String zf = ein.readLine();
                int z = Character.getNumericValue(zf.charAt(0));
                int s = Character.getNumericValue(zf.charAt(1));
                int e = Character.getNumericValue(zf.charAt(2));

                MatrixNew[z][s] = e;

        }
    }
    return MatrixNew;
}
```

I get a 4x4 field consisting of `0`s except for 4 specific locations.
By entering `zse` I am able to change one number on desired position (`[z][s]`) to desired value (`e`). It is kind of like a sudoku field.

What I don't know is how I can effectivly repeat the "change value at position" function to replace all `0`s.

I tried it with a while loop (12 repeats(fixed number)), but the field didn't keep the numbers I had already changed, but showed `0`s again.

**edit:** Added an `if` statement and moved user input into the `if`.
This lets me repeat user input 12 times if all `0`s are changed (correct user input) or 16 times if a `0` is not changed (possibly wrong user input).

The only thing missing now would be printing the 2D Array after every user input.

Comment: Where did you put the loop? Maybe you accidentally put the initialization of  `MatrixNew` inside the loop, causing it to be reset every time.

Comment: I put the while loop in the main function where change() is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you were trying to achieve, but there are several confusions in this code:

1. You use the variable `i` twice - once to init the array, and once as a loop counter. It may work due to scope rules, but best avoid this confusion.
2. You are using two `for` loops to iterate the array, but then are requesting from the user that they specify which cell to enter a number for. This is a confusion, because what the user enters - `[z][s]` - is independent of the `for` loop iterators - `[i][j]`
3. Added a `try()` block to close the stream
4. Not sure from your description which cells you're trying to change ("one number on desired position to desired value") but it is clear you want to print the array each time, so I added that function.

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
static int S = 4; // Don't use variable `i` twice.

static int[][] change() throws IOException {

    // Variable name starts with lower-case
    int matrix[][] = new int[S][S];

    try(BufferedReader ein = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Enter number for cell [%d,%d]:", i, j));
                String line = ein.readLine();
                int e = Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(0));
                matrix[i][j] = e;
                print(matrix);
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

static void print(int[][] m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(m[i][j]);
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.println("]"); // Only here has a "new line"
    }
}
```